# A strategy to update a set of data in mySQL only once

Tags: php, mysql

My website has a daily question and based on selecting the correct answer that users get experience points (XP).

I have two tables in my mySQL database. 1) questionbank 2) users

- Each question has an xp_value (In table questionbank)
- Each user has xp (In table users)

Now, once they answer the correct question I have an if statement with this query:

```
$mysqli->query("UPDATE users SET xp = xp + '$xp_value' WHERE id = '$userID'");
```

Doing so, of course, I successfully update the users xp to a new value, however, the problem is of course the user can go back and answer this question endless amount of times to increase his/her xp.

I am looking for a coding strategy to only UPDATE the xp ONCE and all the other times the user is attempting to answer the question it would give no xp, just to review the question again if he/she desires.

appreciate your time,
oliver_foxx

Comment: To accomplish that, you need to keep track of what questions they answer. You need a DB design where you can say user X answered question A and got experience B. That way, when making an update, you first check if the user already answered that question

Comment: Keep track of all the questions which has been answered by a user. For that you will need a separate table. When a user goes back and again answers the same question you should check against that table. And if there is an entry of that question for that user do give any xp points to that user.

Comment: you are updating only users table, how do you know on which question user got answer?

Comment: Just trying to clarify the structure of the table being suggested by you folks. The new table has the user with the questions and each question has its own column and get the value of lets say 0/1 depending if its been answered or not?

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of the day? As you say its a daily question, XP should only be awarded when the last update was not 'TODAY'.

```
$mysqli->query("UPDATE users SET xp = xp + '$xp_value', `day` = DATE(NOW()) WHERE id = '$userID' AND `day` < DATE(NOW()) ");
```

Comment: It seems to be a good idea for daily questions, however, it might get buggy if there is latency in the upload time for the new question. But I am gonna run it as such and update this comment. thankz!

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need a new table where you can say: User X answered question A this time and day.

When doing an update, you can then easily check if the user already answered the question in place.

You will have two reference tables: user and questions. The questions table will contain the experience for each question.